# How to have two function in an onclick

Tags: javascript, html

How can i call 2 functions with onclick?

```
<input id = "test" onclick="func1()">
```

So how would I added another function into it

Answer (score 2):

Adding a semi-colon will declare the end of a statement allowing you to call another one.

```
<input id = "test" onclick="func1();func2();">
```